# Typescript conditional causes error when stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, conditional-statements, use-reducer

Can someone please explain why the first example works in Typescript, but the second example throws an error??? Here is a [live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCEB2BnGBDTeAXjgG8AoASAGMtcCYAVZYALjlygEtMBzAbiq0c%20QgDU8AGwCuwAPztOPAeQC%20g8khRwJ3PACNJqEhRoRJ0RTG59BlTHgC2bDteWC4nuADcps9pjSjvrAUILq5JoscABi0I7SknhwJlQOzlY2KpTAAI7SeDBcWJnuVFDA2IkwpXxwAD5wgZKSdhAomABCUHjUANbAMNgBQSFhVEm4GCIMzCi12b56hpXsAIJQPYgAPLpcBkYAfOEaWqhxUAlJa9RFWClkVGcLdmB4iBZ4ACYKrlkN6DoongjQuV2SjT2B2AJ0iADNpJhbsVMHBqBVCsAoSsABT0GAuMGJPAAGh8eGWRl%202KMAEpHpQuHC4DiAIRLfYrekVGDSKCo-EwiaDcmU1ZwDZbXYUzlHB4AbQAdMrBYqOdDsABdDSUdUrbCKsDSbAACxxerpOp5fNRpDgysVgrJFsqcAiqki5GEuDgcK4UFwAFEQE4wEYAErAL7SaihB54-AE9hEpJk3p3TDJ%20LEm4Z2lZy7ElKHBne%20CkM5kt4fCDfVQPdMojxebAAdy4MGoZrO9IoVAA9P2AFQjuCBgAaawAsgAFAAygbgAEY4COh4PIl40XhsKgAERocOBtaMQMAfTEa3DAEk1p0F3vWOQt1umSzq58vikSM1JA1GmcEDMh%20tZfkQ4FwHuSh8Hu-5wKyOJ7rQFhQLBPBwCB3y0tygw2q4mLNi%20cDWvyaIYgSNLAAmmJVu8n60hoW5fMAcJ4NUT5EZ4JEComQrPl4Hoel6QIcMAwhfMGoYRlGMZxiQ1FJrE2apnAjYlEphbXMiWD5hp4LFqWIkViwtE1nWDbaZghEcO2nbdiwvaRJQg5rmOk6zgucAAEyriOG5CDu%206Hsep4Xlet73oGj78URZZwFw2AAHIQDAayUfGmFgT%20iR-vUAEsEBGF0aB34kFBbgwXBCFIeY0BoaimXYdZr5wjiCXJallE4bypGCs1XjcWRwCYpRCnAKZ9GMV4zGsexMUvoNfWbgJaiREAA) in a Typescript playground.

```
const {type, payload} = action;

switch(type) {

...

  //*** EXAMPLE 1 ***//

  case "CREATE_VARIABLE":
    if (payload == null || typeof payload === "string" || !("color" in payload)) return state;
    return createVariable(state, payload);

...


  //*** EXAMPLE 2 (Throws error in Typescript) ***//

  case "CREATE_VARIABLE":
    const isNotAVariable = (payload == null || typeof payload === "string" || !("color" in payload));
    if(isNotAVariable) return state;

    return createVariable(state, payload);

...

}
```

The second example throws the following Typescript error:

```
Argument of type 'string | Formula | Variable | Constant | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Variable | undefined'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Variable | undefined'
```

Comment: If you can make this code into a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WGkYJW) (<-- that's a link to your code) then someone can answer with testable code more quickly.  You're probably looking for [a feature that will be released in TS4.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#cfa-aliased-conditions), although you'll need `const` instead of `let`.  But without a reproducible example it's hard to know for sure if that will work for your use case.

Comment: We dont have enough information to answer this for you, we need more context

Comment: I have now added a live example with the full context showing the error in a Typescript playground.

Comment: The link posted by jcalz explains the issue—TS does not currently do deep control flow analysis; the referenced version will enhance it.

Comment: I see now. Thank you @jcalz

Comment: As mentioned above, your example code will work when TS4.4 is released, see [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQKq7m).